# Можно ли замутить на javascript такой проект?

Tags: javascript

[Portal - Still Alive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEfHZtF-5bU)
Можете дать хотя бы ссылки на libs какие-то?

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/BayBzVj

Comment: а помелодичнее? с выбором piano, accordion, flute, clavisin, choir? А так нормально вообще-то!))

Comment: чем богаты, :-)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ого, неожиданно сложно играть, когда нет классического черно-белого разделения))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ у меня сын теперь в твоём codepen залип :))

Comment: Вы не поверите,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLZuBrZ1DsY
я не говорю уже об этом
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCW-qoWWP-Q
и на последок:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JshtQgVRcI

Comment: Макс я рад за твоего сына))) и за сына стрэнджера тоже ))). Ребят, как менять частоту каждой клавиши? скажем 1-я 445 Гц, а вторая - 555 Гц!!!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnmRbSCJe_k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно. Хочу предложить пианино на JavaScript и CSS. Играть можно мышью или на клавиатуре компьютера, так же автоматически. Соотстветствие клавиш на пианино клавишам на компьютере указано на виртуальных клавишах пианино в виде символов. Слишком долго клавиши на клавиатуре компьютера не держите, так как наступит многократное повторение нажатия, как при написании текста. Как лучше от этого избавиться, пока не решил.
Пианино имеет стерезвук с эффектом места расположения клавиш в пространстве. Поддерживается полифония до шести одновременно звучащих нот. Если нажать большее количество клавиш одновременно - консоль выдаст ошибку.
По нажатию имитируется звук трёх струн, настроенных на одну и ту же ноту с определённой погрешностью, степень которой зависит от значения переменной detune.
От переменной rightPedal зависит имитация нажатия на правую педаль настоящего пианино - когда она не нажата, ноты перестают звучать после отпускания клавиш, если нажата - продолжают звучать, пока не затухнут.
Недостаток - подвисает, если маловато свободной оперативной памяти.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="windows-1251">
    <title>Пианино</title>
    <style>
    .white_keys{
        position: absolute;
        background: white;
        border: 2px solid;
        width: 25px;
        height: 200px;
        top: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
        z-index: 0;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 200px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
    }
    .white_keys:hover{
        background: #eee;
    }
    .black_keys{
        position: absolute;
        background: black;
        border: 2px solid;
        border-color: #333;
        width: 15px;
        height: 130px;
        top: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px 0px 7px 7px;
        z-index: 1;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 130px;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
    }
    .black_keys:hover{
        background: #333;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor=#ccc><center><h3>Пианино</h3>
<button id=start1 onclick="playDemo(demoString1)"> Старт демо-1 </button> 
<button id=start2 onclick="playDemo(demoString2)"> Старт демо-2 </button> 
<button onmousedown="clearInterval(demo);start1.disabled=start2.disabled=false;noteDuration=1500"> Стоп демо </button><br><br>
<div id=piano style="position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-300px"></div>
<script>
var rightPedal = true, // Нажата ли правая педаль
transpoze = 0, // Можно использовать для изменения тональности
volume = 0.07, // Громкость
camerton = 110, // Для точной настройки стандартных частот нот
detune = 1.005, // Погрешность настройки струн
fadeOut = 1.00004, // От этого зависит время затухания клавиш
noteDuration = 1500, // Длительность нот
stereo = 50, // Стереоэффект
pan = 1.5, // Стереопанорама в пределах 0 - 2 с дробью
lastPressed = lastReleased = 0, // ID последних нажатой и отжатой клавиш
whiteIndex = 0;
myDown = false;
var frameCount = noteDuration * 44.1;
var akkord = [], str = [], fm = [], samples = [];
var symbols = "zsxdcvgbhnjm,l.;/q2w3e4rt6y7ui9o0p-[]",
demoString1 = "VVgcbWFwXG1YE29XWl9tWmtXDm1SVVrDv1XDv1JOUlVew79aw79V&1500&300",
demoString2 = "cnFyCXAOcg12DnACcg52DXAOcgIOdg5wAw0Pcg52BFAOdAYNEhgacg5wB24Obw10Dm4Cbw50DW4ObwcTdA5uCBQNGm8OdAlVDm4LDRcabw50CTB2w78SGBowdTB2QjB1EhgaMHbDvwkwecO/EhgaMHgweUIweBIYGjB5w78HEy8yd8O/BlLDvwRQw78CTgdTw78HUwZSw78EUHICDnFyCXAOcg12DnACcg52DXAOcgIOdg5wAw0Pcg52BFAOdAYNEhgacg5wB24Obw10Dm4Cbw50DW4ObwcTdA5uCBQNGm8OdAlVDm4LDRcabw50CHRsFBcab3REchQXGnBvCW1sFRgcbXREbRUYHHB0B2NmFBcaa29Cam3DvxMjJmvDv8O/w78HLzJ3&400&130",
keyAsociateEncode = "WlNYRENWR0JITkpNwrxMwr7CusK/UTJXM0U0UlQ2WTdVSTlPMFDCvcObw50=";
var keyAsociate = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(keyAsociateEncode)));
for (var i = 0; i < 37; i++){
    var key = document.createElement("div");
    key.id = i + 12;
    var n = i - 12 * Math.floor(i / 12);
    var keyColor = (n == 1 || n == 3 || n == 6 || n == 8 || n == 10 ? 1 : 0);
    if(keyColor == 1){
        key.className = "black_keys";
    }else{
        key.className = "white_keys";
        whiteIndex++;
    }
    key.setAttribute("data-color", keyColor);
    key.setAttribute("data-left", (19 * keyColor + 28 * whiteIndex) - 36);
    key.style.left = key.dataset.left + "px";
    key.innerHTML = symbols[i];
    key.onmousedown = function(){
        akkord[0] = this.id;
        downKey(akkord);
    }
    key.onmouseup = function(){
        akkord[0] = this.id;
        upKey(akkord);
    }
    key.onmouseout = function(){if(myDown == true)changeStateKey(this, 0)};
    document.getElementById("piano").appendChild(key);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++){
    var amplitude = 1;
    var resonance = 1;
    var polarity = 1;
    var f = Math.pow(1.06, i); // Стандартная частота ноты с номером в i
    samples.push([]);
    for (var h = 0; h < 3; h++)str[h] = Math.pow(detune, Math.random() * 2 - 1);
    for (var j = 0; j < frameCount; j++) {
        if(Math.sin(j / camerton * f) * polarity < 0){
            polarity = -polarity;
            resonance = 1;
        }
        amplitude /= fadeOut;
        resonance /= 1.01;
        for (var h = 0; h < 3; h++)fm[h] = 50 * Math.sin( j / camerton * f * Math.floor(12 / f) * str[h]) * resonance;
        samples[i][j] = 0;
        for (var h = 0; h < 3; h++) {
            var garmony = (j + fm[h]) / camerton * f * str[h];
            samples[i][j] += Math.sin(garmony) + Math.sin(garmony * 2);
        }
        samples[i][j] *= volume * amplitude;
    }
}
document.onmousedown = function(){myDown = true};
document.onmouseup = function(){myDown = false};
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    akkord[0] = keyAsociate.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) + 12;
    if(akkord[0] > 11)downKey(akkord);
}
document.onkeyup=function(e){
    akkord[0] = keyAsociate.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) + 12;
    if(akkord[0] > 11)upKey(akkord);
}
function downKey(e){ // Нажатие клавиши пианино
    lastPressed = e[0].id;
    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    audioCtx.sampleRate = 44100;
    var frameCount = audioCtx.sampleRate * noteDuration / 1000;
    var myArrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(2, frameCount, audioCtx.sampleRate);
    for (var c = 0; c < e.length; c++){
        changeStateKey(document.getElementById(e[c]), 1);
        var stereoSeek = Math.floor((e[c] - 30) * stereo);
        for(lr = 0; lr < 2; lr++){
            var nowBuffering = myArrayBuffer.getChannelData(lr);
            for (var s = 0; s < frameCount; s++){
                var evolute = Math.min((lr * 2 - 1) * ((e[c] / 30) - 1) * pan + 1, 1);
                var sample = samples[parseInt(e[c]) + transpoze][s + stereoSeek * ( lr * 2 - 1)];
                if(sample)nowBuffering[s] += sample * evolute;
            }
        }
    }
    var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = myArrayBuffer;
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.start();
    if(rightPedal == false){
        var vPeriod = setInterval(function(){
            if(lastReleased == lastPressed){
                source.stop();
                clearInterval(vPeriod);
                lastPressed = lastReleased = 0;
            }
        }, 200);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){audioCtx.close()}, noteDuration);
}
function upKey(e){ // Отжатие клавиши пианино
    lastReleased = e[0].id;
    for (var c = 0; c < e.length; c++)changeStateKey(document.getElementById(e[c]), 0);
}
function changeStateKey(id, act){ // Установка состояния клавиш
    if(id){
        var colorBar = ["white", "#ffb", "black", "#009"]; // Цвета для разных состояний клавиш
        id.style.background = colorBar[parseInt(id.dataset.color) * 2 + act];
        id.style.top = (act * 2) + "px";
        id.style.left = (parseInt(id.dataset.left) + act) + "px";           
    }
}
function playDemo(demoString){ // Воспроизведение демок
    start1.disabled = start2.disabled = true;
    var demoArray = demoString.split("&");
    var dbs = decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(demoArray[0])));
    noteDuration = demoArray[1];
    var period = demoArray[2];
    var tc = 0; // time counter
    demo = setInterval(function(){
        if(dbs.charCodeAt(tc) != 255){
            var akkord = [];
            while(dbs.charCodeAt(tc) < 64){
                akkord.push(dbs.charCodeAt(tc));
                tc++;
            }
            akkord.push(dbs.charCodeAt(tc) - 64);
            tc++;
            downKey(akkord);
            setTimeout(function(){upKey(akkord)}, period * 0.75);
        }else{
            tc++;
        }
        if(tc == dbs.length){
            clearInterval(demo);
            start1.disabled = start2.disabled = false;
            noteDuration = 1500;
        }
    }, period);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: piano]