# Вопрос по программе онлайн пианино - не работает клавиша при клике

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Опять проблемы с пианино :(
Пишу приложение онлайн-пианино, вроде все сделала, кроме одного требования - при зажатии клавиши мыши на клавише, перемещаешь курсор на другие клавиши - играют другие ноты.
Проблема с этим такая - перебор по клавишам работает, но не работает звук на той клавише, которую первой зажимаю.
Если у кого-то есть минутка, можете глянь код?
Понимаю, что где-то что-то лишнее написала, но не могу найти, что именно.

Вот js:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    playSound(event.keyCode);
});

const piano = document.querySelector('.piano');
const pianoKeys = document.querySelectorAll('.piano-key');

const playSound = function (keyNumber) {
    const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${keyNumber}"]`);
    const key = document.querySelector(`.piano-key[data-key="${keyNumber}"]`);

    if (!audio) {
        return;
    }

    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();

    key.classList.add('piano-key-active');
};

let removeTransition = function (event) {
    if (event.propertyName !== 'transform') {
        return;
    }
    this.classList.remove('piano-key-active');
};


pianoKeys.forEach(key => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));

const clickPlaySound = function (event) {
    const keyNumber = this.getAttribute("data-key");
    playSound(keyNumber);
};

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

for (let button of buttons) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (this.classList.contains('btn-active')) return;
        buttons.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('btn-active'));

        this.classList.toggle('btn-active');
        piano.classList.toggle('change-style');

    });
}

const startCorrespondOver = (event) => {
    event.target.classList.add('piano-key-active');
    pianoKeys.forEach((key) => {
        key.addEventListener('mouseover', clickPlaySound);
        key.addEventListener('mouseout', removeTransition);
    });
};

const stopCorrecpondOver = () => {
    pianoKeys.forEach((key) => {
        key.classList.remove('piano-key-active');
        key.removeEventListener('mouseover', clickPlaySound);
        key.removeEventListener('mouseout', removeTransition);
    });
};

for (let i = 0; i < pianoKeys.length; i++) {
    pianoKeys[i].addEventListener('mousedown', startCorrespondOver);
    pianoKeys[i].addEventListener('mouseup', stopCorrecpondOver);
}
```

Comment: Приветствую интересное задание, но без HTML-кода не смогу проверить в действии Ваше пианино. Вот на всякий случай моя разработка онлайн-пианино: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1096366/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-javascript-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82/1096495#1096495 Может пригодится.

Answer (score 2):

Ксения, привет! Дам ответ и дам немного конструктивной критики.

Где неправильно:

1. при нажатии мышкой на клавишу произойдёт событие `'startCorrespondOver'`

```
pianoKeys[i].addEventListener('mousedown', startCorrespondOver);
```

2. только после нажатия мышкой в каждую из клавиш добавится событие 'mouseover'

```
key.addEventListener('mouseover', clickPlaySound);
```

Но в нажатую клавишу мышка уже не зайдёт, она уже в ней! Она только выйдет из неё.

Решение "в лоб":
Вызвать `clickPlaySound` сразу по `'mousedown'` по клавише:

```
pianoKeys[i].addEventListener('mousedown', ()=> {
clickPlaySound(event);
startCorrespondOver(event);
);
```

Тут в качестве колбэка используется анонимная стрелочная функция ()=>{doSomething()}

Теперь советы. Расположу их в порядке усложнения.

1. Совет на вашем уровне умения кодить: научитесь логгировать и дебажить.
   Если бы после каждого вызова события вызывали `console.log`, например для `'mouseover'`

```
console.log("На клавишу:"+key+"наехала мышка, вызываем функцию PlaySound")
```

вы бы увидели, что просто не происходит нужного события.

2. Всё дело в том, что вы, судя по всему, разрабатываете прототип и не задумывались об архитектуре и о чистом коде. Изучайте постепенно (но начинайте уже сейчас) чистый код

Вот пример. Проблема в том, когда вы вызываете эту функцию.

```
buttons.forEach(i => i.classList.remove('btn-active'));
```

Поясню. Существует концепция S.O.L.I.D. Следуя последней D., функция, вызванная из модуля нижнего уровня иерархии (один key или button) не должна управлять иерархией более высокого уровня -- всей остальной клавиатурой (keys или buttons).

Эта функция должна быть вызвана по `'mouseup'` (используйте анонимную стрелочную функцию, как в решении выше), и не внутри клавиши, а внутри всего пианино (поясню ниже)

3. Архитектурный подход. Сейчас ваши модули и элементы это просто однородная россыпь предметов. Будто из сумки высыпали все предметы (в том числе предметы из косметички, все монеты из кошелька и т.д.) на стол и они там хаотично валяются. При этом каждый из предметов может неожиданно повлиять на все другие предметы. Например, лак для ногтей протечь и запачкать паспорт. Пока приложение малюсенькое, за этим легко следить. Но кнопка, которая посылает сигнал управления всем остальным кнопкам -- это неправильно. Подписывать всех слушателей на каждую из кнопок это не правильно. Каждая работа должна выполняться на своём уровне иерархии, не выше и не ниже.

Вам нужно создать один единственный объект пианино и на `<div id='piano>` навешивать слушателей `'mousedown'` и `'mouseup'`. Далее из `event` по `event.taget` брать `id` клавиши и передавать этот id отдельно в функцию, управляющую состоянием пианино (какие клавиши в каком состоянии -- аналог того, что вы делаете через атрибуты класса).

`'click'` вам не нужен нигде, достаточно `'mouseup'`

`'mouseover'` и `'mouseout'` действительно нужны на каждой клавише.

Эти три слушателя так же должны изменять только(!) состояние пианино. Состояние пианино это массив из объектов клавиша, у каждой из которых есть несколько свойств.

Далее состояние пианино передаётся в функцию воспроизведения звука.
Далее состояние пианино передаётся в отдельную функцию управления CSS классами.

Кратко так. На эту тему есть много хороших лекций. Для завершения прототипа достаточно первого совета. Для серьёзного программирования без (2) и (3) не обойтись.

Удачи!

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Мне, как начинающему, очень трудно, пошла на курсы. Там пока говорят писать, как получается, сильно не заморачиваться насчет чистоты кода, это будет дальше изучаться.
Постараюсь вникнуть и переписать заново еще раз. А насчет кнопок, вы имели в виду делегирование? Привязать все события к piano?

Comment: У двух учителей ученик без науки... Не буду вмешиваться в программу вашего курса :) На счёт кнопок, да, делегирование на 'mousedown' и 'mouseup'. И прямое назначение на over и out.

Comment: Ксения, вот вам важный поинт, почему нужно хранить состояние пианино в объекте пианино (не элементе `.piano`, а именно объекте `const piano = { }`). Как человеку сыграть аккорд без клавиатуры компьютера, только мышкой? Или если он левой рукой зажмёт несколько кнопок, правой он кликнет мышкой, то весь аккорд сбросится.

Comment: Во втором ответе наверно хотели сказать, что нет смысла функции по событиям вкладывать одну в другую, их можно объявить независимо. (параллельно)

Comment: Олег, нет. Я сказал именно то, что хотел сказать. Независимость (не вложенность) событий и функций возникнет сама собой при соблюдении S. и .D из S.O.L.I.D.

Comment: Понятно. А почему вместо клика достаточно mouseup а не mousedown? Ведь на аккустическом пианино клавиша начинает звучать в момент нажатия, а не отпускания.

Comment: `click` в этом коде работает как сигнал на то, что клавиша отжата. на нажатие используется `mousedown`. Мне кажется, на этот вопрос должна была отвечать автор кода :)

Comment: Тогда получается, что программное отпускание играет роль фактического нажатия. Но как же тогда факти-сски отпускать? :) Если не отпускать, то это то же самое, что все время нажата правая педаль.

Comment: в данном коде программное отпускание играет роль практического ОТжатия, что соответствует поведению классического пианино. Посмотрите на код ещё раз внимательно. И на мои комментарии. По этому (где нажатие, где отжатие) аспекту нигде нет противоречий.

Answer (score 1):

Ну у вас ведь в `startCorrespondOver` нигде не вызывается `clickPlaySound` для этой клавиши, ну которую зажали.

Вот так должно заработать

```
...

const clickPlaySound = function (event) {
    const keyNumber = event.toElement.getAttribute("data-key");
    playSound(keyNumber);
};

const startCorrespondOver = (event) => {
    clickPlaySound(event);
    event.target.classList.add('piano-key-active');
    pianoKeys.forEach((key) => {
        key.addEventListener('mouseover', clickPlaySound);
        key.addEventListener('mouseout', removeTransition);
    });
};

...
```

Comment: Нет, так, к сожалению, вообще не работает :(

Comment: Не заметил - еще в `clickPlaySound` надо поправить. Вот так работает.

Comment: Спасибо большущее, все работает) Сейчас буду разбираться